# Calculus: Derivative of a summation and dot product

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to implement a speed boost to an eye-tracking algorithm (found here: http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/publikationen/pdfs/TiBa11b.pdf). I need to take the derivative of the eye-tracking function, which is as follows:

$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i}^Tg_{i})^{2}$,
where $d_{i} = \frac{x_{i}-c}{\left \| x_{i}-c \right \|_2}$

$X$ and $G$ should be considered constants.

It's been several years since I did any calculus, so I'm flying blind here. How do I take a derivative of a summation? Do I need to take into account the definition of $d$ or the fact that it is a matrix?

Comment: derivative with respect to what?

Comment: I need the derivative with respect to c. X and G are constant. The derivative with respect to d would work as well.

Comment: The sum of a derivative is the derivative of the sum. I'm not entirely sure which things in your expression are matrices and which are scalars, but if you write out the formulas for matrix multiplication and take the derivative, you will find that the product rule holds: if $A(t),B(t)$ are matrix valued functions, then $d(A(t)B(t))=A'(t)B(t)+A(t)B'(t)$. If $A$ commutes with $A'$, you can use this plus induction to show that the power rule also works. Things like this let you do calculus on matrices without writing things out term by term and entry by entry.

Comment: I'm very slowly getting back up to speed with calculus, but that was over my head. Can you explain with less high-level language? And could I see the steps to find the derivative of this?